# Creating container image without docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

Is it possible to build a container image as a simple user account on a system which does not have docker or podman installed? In other words, is there a user-space tool/application which can build an image that could run on a different system which supports OCI containers, such as AKS, etc.

Comment: Do you build a docker from your Dockerfile in a machine without docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image is based on the [OCI image-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/spec.md) which consists of filesystem layers packaged as tar files, a config json, and a manifest. All of these are referenced with a content addressable digest. If you can create these tar and json files, then you can create an image without a runtime.

There are various tools that do this for specific cases. I think most are shipped as containers and designed to run in CI pipelines, but you can probably get standalone binaries. However, I don't think any of these work with a Dockerfile, so if you need something that supports that syntax, you'll need a container runtime. There are rootless runtimes, but they typically have prerequisites that need to be performed on the host by root in advance, and there's a performance hit from using them.

Comment: As far as I know, [`buildah bud`](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/01/11/getting-started-with-buildah) is able to work with dockerfiles without a full container runtime environment.

Comment: @Turing85 for the `RUN` steps, I'm pretty sure you'll need a runtime. Running it outside of a container wouldn't be very reproducible (but then they use all kinds of host resources with that tool). What you can do is have that tool be rootless, and I think RHEL has been baking in the prereqs for that, along with other newer Linux distros.

Comment: I did find an interesting writeup based on ideas from your answer: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/08/14/best-practices-for-running-buildah-in-a-container#

Answer (score 0):

Podman and Buildah are userspace tools. They don't require root access. They can also build `oci` and `docker` images,

> Recognized formats include oci (OCI image-spec  v1.0,  the  default)  and  docker (version 2, using schema format 2 for the manifest).

Note while Buildah can build from a dockerfile, you really shouldn't ever create dockerfiles. The normal method of operation with buildah involves creating a shell script, which provides you amongst other things a path into the off-line mount point, shell expansion, and conditionals, and the ability to run things in the container before committing (great for initialization).

Here is a quick example without dockerfile, `build_image.sh`

```shell
#!/bin/bash

ctr=$(buildah from alpine:3)
mnt=$(buildah mount "$ctr")

mkdir "$mnt/rootleveldir"
cp ./localfile "$mnt/rootleveldir"

buildah run -v "$PWD:$PWD" -- sh $PWD/init.sh

buildah config --entrypoint "/rootleveldir" --cmd "run.sh";

buildah commit                 \
  --author "Evan Carroll"      \
  --rm                         \
  "$ctr" "localhost:myimage";
```

Create the image without root with `buildah unshare ./build_image.sh`

Podman can commit any online container to an image, and buildah can commit any offline container to an image.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Even though they are user space tools, they require the system they run on to be set up in a specific way by an administrator. Hence a user can't build or run podman/buildah on a system which is not set up for them to work already.

Comment: @Plazgoth I'm not sure what you mean. You can use mount without unshare, and unshare puts you in a namespace that has to be created (which requires root). But the rest afaik will run just fine with builldah https://opensource.com/article/19/3/tips-tricks-rootless-buildah

Comment: @Plazgoth perhaps try it, get an error, ask with that error.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting I try. To build a buildah executable from source?

Comment: @Plazgoth Sure. that's one method. Or use your package manager to download it. Then extract it from the package and put it in `~/.locall/bin` and add that to your path.

Comment: I did try it and here is the error:
$ buildah --version && buildah help

buildah version 1.11.6 (image-spec 1.0.1-dev, runtime-spec 1.0.1-dev)
Error during unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER): Invalid argument
User namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces.
ERRO error parsing PID "": strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax
ERRO (unable to determine exit status)

Comment: @Plazgoth Right, you need user-namespaces enabled in the kernel. That has nothing to do with buildah though, you can't do _anything_ with rootless containers without user namespaces enabled. It's a kernel thing. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303214/3285